# Positioning text and image?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/vy6w2tun/1/

```
<html>
</html>
```

(1) The text is centered in the page, which is what I want.

(2) However, I would like the image centered (which it is), but I do not want the text to cover the image. I would like the image to go below the text, so that no part of the image is being covered by the text, and vice-versa.

How would I go about doing so?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add the applicable code (only code that pertains to your question) into the post. This will help more people assist you faster and show that you have taken the time to reduce your problem as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

i deleted `position:absolute;` and `top` `left` values and `transform` values from p { }. İ added `margin:0 auto;` (for center) and `width:70%;` in p {}.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box
        }
        
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0
        }
        
        @font-face {
            font-family: HelveticaNeueLTCom-Th;
            src: url("HelveticaNeueLTCom-Th.ttf")
        }
        
        p {
            font-family: HelveticaNeueLTCom-Th;
            font-size: 19pt;
            letter-spacing: 1.2px;
            color: red;
            line-height: 1.5;
            text-align: justify;
            margin:0 auto;
            width:70%; /* it's up to you */
        }
        
        .fullscreen-bg {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            z-index: -100
        }
        
        .fullscreen-bg__video {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%
        }
        
        .img {
            display: grid;
            height: 100%
        }
        
        .center-fit {
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 90vh;
            margin: auto
        }
        
        @media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
            .fullscreen-bg__video {
                height: 300%;
                top: -100%
            }
        }
        
        @media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
            .fullscreen-bg__video {
                width: 300%;
                left: -100%
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="fullscreen-bg">
        <video loop autoplay muted src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" class="fullscreen-bg__video"></video>
    </div>
    <p>In publishing and graphic design, lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document without relying on meaningful content. Replacing the actual content with placeholder text allows designers to design the form of the content before the content itself has been produced.</p>
    <div class="img"> <img class="center-fit" src='https://grcc.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Dogs-for-Rob-1-e1434850228704-1024x695.jpg'></div>
    <div class="img"> <img class="center-fit" src='https://picsum.photos/400/300'></div>
    <div class="img"> <img class="center-fit" src='https://picsum.photos/400/300'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can use `width: 100%`; maybe just use margin or padding with it then. You beat me to it though. :)